# .NET Framework name space structure (Directives)

Tags: namespaces

For example "Using System.Console". Here "System" is the namespace and "Console" is the class"

Okay that makes sence but what about directives such as "System.IO.Compression".

In the above example would "Compression" be the method?

In visual studio projects why does the IDE add using system; and then using system.console?

Would using system automatically call all the classes in the namespace anyway making the using system.console redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System`, `System.Console`, `System.IO`, `System.IO.Compression` are all namespaces.

```
namespace System
{
   class Foo1{}
   namespace Console
   {
   }
   namespace IO
   {
     class Foo2{}
     namespace Compression{}
   }
}
```

`Compression` namespace is nested inside `IO`, and all nested inside `System`

If you `Using System`, you only can access class `Foo1()`, in the other words, `Using...` only access class and variable, not the namespace that nested inside

***EDIT: This article defines quite clearly about namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s(v=vs.140).aspx